# I am facing A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: database, timer, countdown, suspend

When I try to access my website member login area, I experiencing multiple errors those were not there earlier.
Please help me look into it.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: number
>
> Filename: controllers/Site.php
>
> Line Number: 42
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/internetsunivers/2xcash.internetsuniversity.com/application/controllers/Site.php
>   Line: 42 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/internetsunivers/2xcash.internetsuniversity.com/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/internetsunivers/2xcash.internetsuniversity.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 564
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/internetsunivers/2xcash.internetsuniversity.com/application/controllers/Site.php
>   Line: 50 Function: redirect
>
> File: /home/internetsunivers/2xcash.internetsuniversity.com/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

Following is the code in site.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends MY_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->header(':::SONNY SERVER:::');
    $data['site_name'] = $this->site_name;
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->footer();
}

public function about() {
    $this->header('About | '.$this->site_name);
    $data['site_name'] = $this->site_name;
    $this->load->view('about');
    $this->footer();
}

public function faq() {
    $this->header('FAQ | '.$this->site_name);
    $data['site_name'] = $this->site_name;
    $this->load->view('faq');
    $this->footer();
}
public function support() {
    $this->header('Contact Support | '.$this->site_name);
    $data['site_name'] = $this->site_name;
    $this->load->view('support');
    $this->footer();
}

public function login() {

    $this->header('Login');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Phone Number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        if ($this->core_model->login()) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('number' => $number));
            $result = $query->row_array();

            $name = $result['name'];
            $bank_details = $result['bank_details'];
            $session_data = array('number' => $_POST['number'], 'loggedin' => TRUE, 'name' => $name);
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

            redirect(site_url('dash'));

        }
        elseif ($this->db->get_where('users', array('number' => $this->input->post('number'), 'is_blocked' => 'true'))->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Account has been blocked, contact suppport');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Login failed');

        }

        $this->load->view('login');

    } else {

        $this->load->view('login');

    }
}

public function register() {
    $this->header('Register | '.$this->site_name);
    $data['site_name'] = $this->site_name;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Fullname', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Phone Number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bundle', 'Bundle', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank_details', 'Bank Details', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');
    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $this->core_model->register();
    //register session
    $session_data = array('number' => $_POST['number'], 'loggedin' => TRUE, 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'bank_details' => $_POST['bank_details']);
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg2', 'Successfully registered');
    redirect(site_url('spillover'));
    $this->load->view('register');
} else {
    $this->load->view('register');
}
    $this->footer();
}

public function logout() {

    $data = array('number', 'loggedin', 'name');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($data);

    redirect('login');
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: code for site.php added as for other codes text enter limit reach